# How can I reference an AR model from inside another module of the same name?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named `Promotion`.

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base; 
  FORMATS = [0,1]
end
```

I also have another subclass named 'Promotion' defined in a file in the /lib folder of my app.

```
module Faker
  module MyProject
    module Promotion
      def format
        # Need to access Promotion::FORMATS
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I need to reference a constant defined in the AR class from within the other module. <strike>The only way I've been able to do it so far is to use</strike>

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.detect{|model| model.name == 'Promotion'}::FORMATS
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this?

**CORRECTION**

Turns out that only worked from the command line. When I applied it to the Promotion submodule, it didn't return the same list of models. So rather than a better way, what is *the* way to access an AR model in a non-ambiguous way? I've updated the definitions above to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of how constants are scoped.

The simple answer is

```
::Promotion
```

In your example

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

Promotion has been defined on the global scope so can be accessed in 3 ways

- Promotion
- ::Promotion
- Object::Promotion

But within your module `Faker::MyProject` any reference to `Promotion` will look up this namespace

If `Faker::MyProject::Promotion` exists it'll return this.

I suggest you make a habit of refering to `::Promotion` in these type of cases.

Example:

```
class A; end
module B; class A; end

A         #=> A
::A       #=> A
Object::A #=> A

B.module_eval("A")   #=> B::A
B.module_eval("::A") #=> A
```

Comment: Damn, that was quick. And simple. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Chris, I see you edited your question. Not sure if that was before or after my answer. Does using `::Promotion` still fix your problem? I f you really want to find subclasses of ActiveRecord, try `ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses` you'll need to consider whether the class has already been loaded if using this in development.

Comment: You posted your answer while I was in the middle of revising my question, but your answer solved it for me.